# Obtain file sizes in MSBuild script

Tags: msbuild

Can I find out the sizes of a set of files from an MSBuild script without writing my own code?

MSBuild itself some metadata on individual items (for example, the last modified time at %(ModifiedTime)
), but no sizes. I can't see anything at http://msbuildextensionpack.com/.

**Edit:** based on Seva's answer, here's an inline task that returns the total size of an array of items:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetFileSize" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Files ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
    <TotalSize ParameterType="System.Int64" Output="true"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
        long l = 0;
        foreach (var item in Files) {
            var fi = new FileInfo(item.ItemSpec);
            l += fi.Length;
        }
        TotalSize = l;
]]></Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use a sub-set of .Net API within msbuild projects using [inline tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx).

E.g. the following prints out a file size of a single file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetFileSize" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <FileName Required="true" />
    <FileSize ParameterType="System.Int64" Output="true"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System.IO"/>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName);
FileSize = fi.Length;
]]></Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="PrintFileSize" >
  <GetFileSize FileName="$(MyFileName)">
    <Output TaskParameter="FileSize" PropertyName="MyFileSize" />
  </GetFileSize>
  <Message Text="file size of $(MyFileName) is $(MyFileSize)" />
</Target>
```